# Why is instance function generating excess objects? (Godot 4.1.1)

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

This is a script i use for my game's **tree chopping system**, problem is it keeps **generating excess** fallen tree objects and possibly stumps the number it spawns correspond with the number of base unchopped tree instances i have in my scene, for example if i have 3 base trees in my scene and i chop one it will spawn 3 fallen trees. Help would be much appreciated.

Bear with me the whole script is needed to be shown for full understanding.

This is my code:

```
extends Node3D

var tree_fallen = preload("res://Assets/Trees/pine_tree_fallen.tscn")
var tree_stump = preload("res://Assets/Trees/pine_tree_stump.tscn")

@onready var ray = get_node("../../../Player/Head/Camera3D/TreeHitRay")

var clicks = 0

var timer = Timer.new()

var chopNewTreeTimer = Timer.new()

func _ready():
    timer.wait_time = 0.5
    timer.one_shot = true
    # Add the timer as a child of the node
    add_child(timer)

    chopNewTreeTimer.wait_time = 0.25
    chopNewTreeTimer.one_shot = true
    # Add the timer as a child of the node
    add_child(chopNewTreeTimer)

func _process(_delta):
    # Check if the raycast is colliding with an object
    if ray.is_colliding():
        # Get the object
        var obj = ray.get_collider()
        var obj_local = obj.get_parent()
        

        # Check if the left mouse button is pressed
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Attack") and timer.is_stopped():
            # Increment the clicks
            clicks += 1
            timer.start()
            # Check if the clicks reach 3
            if clicks == 3:
                clicks = 0
                spawn_trees(obj_local)
func spawn_trees(obj_local):
    # Get main scene
    var main = get_node("/root/World/Stage/Trees/TreeByproducts")
    var TreeParentGLobalPos = obj_local.global_position
    
    var TreeSceneRoot = ray.get_collider().get_parent()
    TreeSceneRoot.queue_free()
    # Instantiate the fallen tree scene
    var fallen_tree = tree_fallen.instantiate()
    # Add the fallen tree to the main scene
    main.add_child(fallen_tree)
    # Set its position to the object's position
    fallen_tree.global_position = TreeParentGLobalPos
    # Instantiate the stump scene
    var stump = tree_stump.instantiate()
    # Add the stump to the main scene
    main.add_child(stump)
    # Set its position to the object's position
    stump.global_position = TreeParentGLobalPos
    # Delete the old tree
    fallen_tree.rotation.x = randf_range(2.0,5.0)
    fallen_tree.rotation.z = randf_range(2.0,5.0)
```

Try to chop one tree, the game will spawn excess fallen trees.

Comment: is this script attached to each trees?

Comment: yes it is attached to each base unchopped tree scene, also thx for the fast reply :).

Comment: oh wait that question just made me realize it will do the same process for each tree script i think? so i need to make script apart of something else

Comment: omg i'm right, i  fixed it i know it was just a question but it helped so much thx.